# Where does ExtJS Action fit into MVC pattern

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I really like concept of ExtJS Actions. I looked [at this example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/menu/action-grid.html) and it is (almost) exactly what I need. Only thing is that I'm trying to use MVC pattern.
I have:

- invoicelist (view)
- Inovice (controller)
- Invoice (model)
- Invoices (store)

Where and how do I put definition for Action? Should they be in controller? How to call them and reference them? I need several Actions and they will be in context menu and in menu in invoicelist's toolbar.

Answer (score 6):

Good question. It seems Actions break the MVC pattern by somehow combining View and Controller paradigms under one roof. Because they have handlers they carry functionality with them as well as UI elements like text and icons. However they are not components  - in ExtJS sense of the word. Hence you can't target them with a selector.

The best way to think of them is as a config object. No more, no less. A config object is meaningless by itself - and can not be targeted. Same with Actions. They can actually be used as a config object to buttons for example.

Now where should they go? The answer to that I guess is really up to you as a designer. Since they don't confirm to strict MVC pattern you get to make a decision based on how widely you need a particular action be accessible. For a truly global action that is shared by many views  you might even put it in the application config: MyApp.app.actions["delete"]  for example.
Controller might be a good place to put it if that controller will configure multiple views and wire them together with stores. They can potentially wire up multiple views with shared actions.

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently trying to create some Actions that will all be used in one view. It is Window with toolbar and grid. Action will appear in toolbar submenu, and in context menu when user right clicks on grid row. For this scenario I believe I should put it in Controller for this Window, right? How? I used to wire events from controller to views but don't know how to INSERT objects in UI.

Comment: What I would do then is create actions in your view class and have the action handlers fire some custom events. In your controller class you can listen for those custom events emitting from your view.

Comment: Code snippet for firing custom events from actions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: as already mentioned in additional answer below a custom event is fired like this::  someview.fireEvent('Yourcustomevent', someData);

Answer (score 1):

just do a `someview.fireEvent('Yourcustomevent');`